# Animating material property differently for every object that uses the same material

Tags: animation, node-editor

I have a plenty of lanterns in my scene that use the same material and I would like to animate their emission value independently. Currently I've animated it using noise f curve modifier to achieve subtle flickering however it's all synchronised with other lanterns (as I expected)

I know that you can achieve different colors of objects within the same material by using object info random imput and I'm wondering if something similar could be done with animating like each object would have different noise phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're being economical, you just need 2 dimensions of noise.

[image]

For example:

- The `#frame` - driven 'Frame' input samples a 'scanline' across the X of a 2D *Musgrave* texture.
- The 'Random' output of an *Object Info* node decides at what Y the texture's X is scanned. The Y's are kept well apart by the multiplier.

The 'Scale' of the noise determines the frequency of the flicker.. maybe the 'Detail' could be used to determine the flicker's jitter, depending on which noise you use.

[image]

If you needed the animation to loop, you would need another dimension of noise.

A multiple of `#frame` could then be interpreted as an angle `theta`, arranged to be `0` at the beginning of the loop and `2 * pi` at the end.  X and Y would be `sin` and `cos` of `theta` , tracing a circle in an XY slice of 3D noise. The *Object Info* node would determine which Z the slice was at.